# how to display double quote instead of &34; from php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, double-quotes

I am pulling my hair with this simple task...
From a php variable that contains double quotes (") which is echoed in a div, the html source shows that " have been replaced by `&#34;`.  So far OK.
However, when the html code within the div is copied with jQuery, some of the double quotes are repeated.
I need to fix that in order to use MindMup editor properly.

```
$Text = 'This is an <span class="myclass">example</span> where double-quotes are added by "I don\'t know what".'
<a onclick="javascript:copyEditor();">copy code</a>
<div id="editor">
echo $Text;
</div>

<script>
function copyEditor() { 
  $('#hiddenEditor').html($('#editor').html()); 
}
</script>
```

If the text is typed directly into the html page with double quotes, then it is fine.  See the difference in [that example](http://www.paulgodard.com/Alpha/PageTest.php#).

So my question is how do I stop php/html to convert the double quotes into " when displaying that variable in the page?

There is also an empty line added on top in the link above after copying the code... why?

Answer (score 1):

Replace double quotes with `&quot;`

To replace the quotes in user input:
$escaped_quotes =  str_replace( "\"", """, $string );

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: I am not sure I understand... would you do that on the php variable $Text before displaying it in the div tag?